# How to return an JSON object I made in a reduce function

Tags: list, couchdb

I need your help about CouchDB reduce function.
I have some docs like:

```
{'about':'1', 'foo':'a1','bar':'qwe'}
{'about':'1', 'foo':'a1','bar':'rty'}
{'about':'1', 'foo':'a2','bar':'uio'}
{'about':'1', 'foo':'a1','bar':'iop'}
{'about':'2', 'foo':'b1','bar':'qsd'}
{'about':'2', 'foo':'b1','bar':'fgh'}
{'about':'3', 'foo':'c1','bar':'wxc'}
{'about':'3', 'foo':'c2','bar':'vbn'}
```

As you can seen they all have the same key, just the values are differents.
My purpse is to use a Map/Reduce and my return expectation would be:

```
'rows':[ 'keys':'1','value':{'1':{'foo':'a1', 'at':'rty'},
                             '2':{'foo':'a2', 'at':'uio'},
                             '3':{'foo':'a1', 'at':'iop'}}
         'keys':'1','value':{'foo':'a1', 'bar','rty'}
          ...
         'keys':'3','value':{'foo':'c2', 'bar',vbn'}
       ]
```

Here is the result of my Map function:

```
'rows':[ 'keys':'1','value':{'foo':'a1', 'bar','qwe'}
         'keys':'1','value':{'foo':'a1', 'bar','rty'}
          ...
         'keys':'3','value':{'foo':'c2', 'bar',vbn'}
       ]
```

But my Reduce function isn't working:

```
function(keys,values,rereduce){
  var res= {};
  var lastCheck = values[0];
  for(i=0; i<values.length;++i)
  {
    value = values[i];
    if (lastCheck.foo != value.foo)
    {
      res.append({'change':[i:lastCheck]});
    }
    lastCheck = value;
   }
   return res;
 }
```

Is it possible to have what I expect or I need to use an other way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not do this in the reduce function. As the  [couchdb wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views#Map_Functions) explains:-

> If you are building a composite return structure in your reduce, or only transforming the values field, rather than summarizing it, you might be misusing this feature.

There are two approaches that you can take instead

1. Transform the results at your application layer.
2. Use the [list function](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/transforming.html#example).

Lists functions are simple. I will try to explain them here:

Lists like views are saved in design documents under the key lists. Like so:

```
"lists":{

  "formatResults" : "function(head,req) {....}" 

}
```

To call the list function you use a url like this

`http://localhost:5984/your-database/_design/your-designdoc/_list/your-list-function/your-view-name`

Here is an example of list function

```
function(head, req) {
  var row = getRow();
  if (!row){
    return 'no ingredients'
   }

  var jsonOb = {};

  while(row=getRow()){
     //construct the json object here
  }
     return {"body":jsonOb,"headers":{"Content-Type" : "application/json"}};
}
```

The `getRow` function is of interest to us. It contains the result of the view. So we can query it like

`row.key` for key

`row.value` for value

All you have to do now is construct the json like you want and then `send` it.

By the way you can use [log](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#Debugging_Views)
to debug your functions.

I hope this helps a little.

Comment: I have read information about list function but cleary not understand how it works and how use it.

In time what solution would be the best ?

Comment: It would be better if you can add a new question with a concise question about your reduce function. This solution will probably work on a small database, but be totally inefficient on anything with more than a few megabytes.

Comment: @Akshat Jiwan Sharma  thank you so much, I missed the fact that I have to give to the url the name of my design document in order to make it work !!! After reading that it really seems to provide me what I need ! Thank you ! Sorry I can't 'vote up' because of my lack of reputation

Comment: I am just happy I could be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently now you need to use

```
provides('json', function() { ... });
```

As in: 
[Simplify Couchdb JSON response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949689/simplify-couchdb-json-response)